# Recursive function to scan to the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, recursion

I'm reading Marijn Haverbeke's Eloquent Javascript. I come from a Flash/AS3 programming background but feel this book will be useful in getting me up to scratch fast. Below is the HTML and a JS snippet that scans the DOM for a match to see if a particular node has a given string:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My home page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My home page</h1>
    <p>Hello, I am Marijn and this is my home page.</p>
    <p>I also wrote a book! Read it
      <a href="http://eloquentjavascript.net">here</a>.</p>
  </body>
</html>

function talksAbout(node, string) {
  if (node.nodeType == document.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
      if (talksAbout(node.childNodes[i], string))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  } else if (node.nodeType == document.TEXT_NODE) {
    return node.nodeValue.indexOf(string) > -1;
  }
}

console.log(talksAbout(document.body, "book"));
// → true
```

I get functions, arrays, and the general syntax of course, but how does the following line work exactly.

```
if (talksAbout(node.childNodes[i], string))
        return true;
```

A general explanation if this function would be useful to me as it is not broken down into detail in the book. Thanks!

Comment: What part exactly confuses you? You seem to understand that it's recursive.

Answer (score 0):

It's a recursive function.

That means it's a function that calls itself (to go deeper into an object/do further processing).

Everytime your talksAbout function finds a ELEMENT_NODE, it will browse into the ELEMENT_NODE until it encounters a TEXT_NODE.

When it finds a TEXT_NODE it will evaluate if the string appears as given in the text. and then return that result all the way back up the chain.

So what it does is:

- talksAbout(document.body)

  - talksabout(document.body.h1)

    - talksabout(document.body.h1.text)
      return false
    - return false
  - return false
- result = false
- next node

  - talksAbout(document.body.p)

    - talksabout(doucment.body.p.text)
      return false
    - return false
  - return false
- result = false
- next node

  - talksAbout(document.body.p)

    - talksabout(doucment.body.p.text)
      return true
    - return true
  - return true
- return true